# Configurations and pressure-temperature phase diagrams

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

The questions here arise out of investigating theoretical straight-line pressure-temperature phase diagrams for suites of minerals in chemically-similar metamorphic rocks. I've tried to phrase the questions in purely mathematical terms. All points and lines lie in a single Euclidean plane.

We start with a set of c+4 labels

Consider a configuration of <sub>c+4</sub>C<sub>2</sub> points and <sub>c+4</sub>C<sub>3</sub> lines
with three points per line and c+2 lines per point wherein:
    a) each point is uniquely identified by a pair of labels
    b) each line is uniquely identified by a triple of labels and
       each point lying on a given line is identified by two of the three
       labels in the triple identifying the line

Questions:

1. For c=1 must we have a Desargues configuration?
   edit: I believe the answer is yes (and it's actually rather trivial); perspective from a point is definitely a requirement.
2. In all discovered configurations for c=1 and c=2 we have:
   1 point adjacent to 2*(c+2)
   2 points adjacent to 2*(c+2)-1
   3 points adjacent to 2*(c+2)-2
   ...
   c+3 points adjacent to 2*(c+2)-(c+2)
   Must this always be true?

[image: simple c=1 example (Desargues configuration)]
[image]
  [

Comment: A picture might help.

Comment: I can't draw - the blue line at the right goes through points de, cd, and ce

Comment: That's a good picture, actually, and it does help.

Comment: Found an old drawing for c=2, so added it also for illustrative purposes.